# Not able to find object from DB right after I created It

Tags: django, postgresql, nose

I was testing User creation by creating a TestCase, and it couldn't be found right after I created it.

I've tried to flush the cache by calling `.refresh_from_db()`, but it doesn't work.

Here is my TestCase:

```
class SuperStrangeTest(TestCase):
    def test_super_strange(self):
        john = User.objects.create()
        john.refresh_from_db()

        print('!=====START' * 10)
        print(User.objects.count())
        print(User.objects.all())
        self.assertIsNotNone(User.objects.filter().first()) # None of assertions below would be right
        self.assertIsNotNone(User.objects.filter(id=john.id).first())
        self.assertTrue(User.objects.filter(id=john.id).exists())
```

My command to run this test is:

`./manage.py test --noinput --failfast --keepdb links.tests.SuperStrangeTest.test_super_strange`

The result sometimes went right, but most times it is just broken.

```
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
/Users/oldcai/.virtualenvs/web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grequests.py:21: MonkeyPatchWarning: Patching more than once will result in the union of all True parameters being patched
  curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
!=====START!=====START!=====START!=====START!=====START!=====START!=====START!=====START!=====START!=====START
1
<QuerySet [<User: >]>
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_super_strange (links.tests.SuperStrangeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oldcai/programs/python/webproject/zine/links/tests.py", line 41, in test_super_strange
    self.assertIsNotNone(User.objects.filter().first())
AssertionError: unexpectedly None

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Ran 1 test in 0.130s

FAILED (failures=1)
Preserving test database for alias 'default'...
```

Errors of other lines:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_super_strange (links.tests.SuperStrangeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oldcai/programs/python/webproject/links/tests.py", line 35, in test_super_strange
    self.assertTrue(User.objects.filter(id=john.id).exists())
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_super_strange (links.tests.SuperStrangeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oldcai/programs/python/webproject/links/tests.py", line 35, in test_super_strange
    self.assertTrue(User.objects.filter(id=john.id).exists())
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fill your model fields. It's base Django User model - it requires username and password. Also to create django user - use `create_user` function, that function will hash the password for you. Try to correct you code like that:

```
...
john = User.objects.create_user(username='john', password='password')
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've already tried this way or use a library(model_mommy) to create the model, it seems that the result is just the same.

Comment: I'm using john = User.objects.create() just because it's easy to understand. I'm sure it works, and sometimes, the TestCase just passes without any Error or Failure.

Answer (score 0):

After diagnosed deeper into this issue, it appears that this error relates to my `DATABASE_ROUTERS` setting.

I'm routing the reading part of operations to a random read-only slave database in production to balancing the load of reading.

In TestCase, I set the configs of the slave database just equal to the default one.

```
DATABASE = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'test',
    'PASSWORD': 'test',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
}

DATABASES = {
    'default': DATABASE,
    'replica1': DATABASE,
}
```

But it still not able to query out the result with `replica1` right after a record inserted by `default` database.

When the router randomly chose the `default` database as the one to read from, the TestCase would pass, otherwise, it would fail.